# How could I get the value of seekbar in service class if the toggle button is checked

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I am making a project in which i am using a toggle button and a seekbar. I am able to save the value of toggle button using shared prefrences but i am not able to work using seekbar. In this I want if the toggle button is checked than only the broadcast receiver must work and the broadcast receiver must start the service... The code that i did is...

In the xml file I did this coding..

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:progress="5"
    android:secondaryProgress="10"
    android:max="40"
    android:layout_marginTop="136dp" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    />
```

in the Activity class..

```
      TextView tv;
    SeekBar sb;
    SharedPreferences spref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = spref.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(sb.getProgress()));
        spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        editor = spref.edit();
        int aprog=sb.getProgress();
        editor.putInt("mMySeekBarProgress", aprog).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        int mProgress = spref.getInt("mMySeekBarProgress", 0);
        sb.setProgress(mProgress);
        sb.setSecondaryProgress(40);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

In the BroadcastReceiver class...

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean Enable = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("is toggle enable", false);
    int ee=context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("sbar", 0);
    if(Enable){
        //Toast.makeText(context, "in on receive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    Intent it = new Intent(context, myserve.class);

    it.putExtra("i", ee);
    context.startService(it);
}
}
```

In the Service class...

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    //I want to use toast here to display value of seek bar
    int ii=intent.getExtras().getInt("i");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "i= "+ii, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Using this I am able to save the state of a togglebutton as well as seekbar and i am able to get the progress value as a toast but the problem when i exit from activity and again i come back and make some change it doesnot show that toast value untill i once change togglebutton from on to off and viceversa

Comment: Do you want to save the state of the toggle button as well as SeekBar in the shared preferences at once?

Comment: I am able to save the state of toggle button but i am not able to save the state of seekbar and i want to save that also

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a mistake in saving the progress value of the seekbar.
Here is the code that captures both the state of the Toggle button and the SeekBar.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnCheckedChangeListener, OnClickListener{

private SeekBar mSeekBar;
private ToggleButton mToggleButton;
private int mSeekBarProgress;
private SharedPreferences mValuePrefs;
private Button mBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    mToggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    mBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    mBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    mValuePrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

//SeekBar
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    mSeekBarProgress = progress;        
}


@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mSeekBarProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
    //Save value in shared prefs
    Editor editor = mValuePrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("seekbar", mSeekBarProgress);
    editor.commit();
    }

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

//Toggle button
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         //checked is true - save value in shared prefs
    Editor editor = mValuePrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("toggle", isChecked);
    editor.commit();
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btn){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

**SecondActivity.java** used to display the values saved in shared preference:

```
  public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

private static  String TAG = "SecondActivity";
private TextView mTxt;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.value);

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    int seekbar = mPrefs.getInt("seekbar", 0);
    boolean toggle = mPrefs.getBoolean("toggle", false);

    Log.d(TAG,"Toggle "+toggle+" : SeekBar "+seekbar);

    mTxt.setText("Toggle "+toggle+" : SeekBar "+seekbar);

}
```

}

Comment: thanks i made some changes in my code and i am able to save it but i am going through a problem could you look over it

Comment: sure. Let me know what is the issue